# Windows username in the filename of the log4net output

Tags: c#, vb.net, log4net

I'm implementing a VB.NET (C# is ok too) app that will be run in the same time by different users.

I need to log all users events in separate files named like thiswindowsuser-20170103.log

Is possible to configure log4net to work this way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question should be: Is it possible to output environment variables, since you have `USERNAME` and `USERDOMAIN`.

And yes this should be possible with

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%env{USERNAME}.log" />
```

or even

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="${USERNAME}.log" />
```

according to https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html example with `TMP` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jürgen. very useful information. Is it possible with any other variable other than environment variables? just curious:)

Comment: @shreesha Look at the examples link I provided and https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html You can even add your own properties: http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-6-Log-Event-Context.aspx